# Is it possible to utilize the XML file that I saved xml file in Appium Inspector of the current screen instead of driver

Tags: mobile, automated-tests, appium, ui-automation, appium-android

I am writing an automation for an app. there is one screen that appears only for 30 minutes each day.
so i saved the 4 screens that matters from appium inspecter as a xml file.

now i want my code to think that instead of appium driver from real device this xml file is a source for that
any help will be really appreciated.

I have saved the xml file of current screen using appium inspector. now i need to feed this xml as appium driver so that my method works as it would on actual screen.